# Bulk Deleting Mailboxes with PowerShell - Exchange 2016

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to delete 100+ mailboxes from our cloud hosted Exchange server with PowerShell, but I keep getting this error:

The operation couldn't be performed because object '...' couldn't be found on '...'

The blanks are obviously an object from the array and our Exchange server. I am pulling the objects (I have tried both Email Addresses and Display Names) from a .csv file with the header 'mailbox'. I have used Disable-Mailbox and Remove-Mailbox, to no avail.

Here is my script:

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\array.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Mailbox -identity $_.mailbox -confirm:$false
}
```

I have been Googling all day and I can't seem to find the reason why these objects, that are in fact mailboxes in our Exchange environment, can't be found.

Comment: I would do a `Get-Mailbox` and pipe it into `| Remove-Mailbox`. Make sure to use `-Whatif` to make sure you are deleting what you intend to delete.

Comment: Get-Mailbox will retrieve all mailboxes on our server though. How would I go about using an entire .csv list of email addresses as a condition that must be met in order to be deleted? It is surprising to me that an initial array of objects that I want deleted isn't enough.

Comment: As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/remove-mailbox?view=exchange-ps#required-parameters) explain: 
The Identity parameter identifies the mailbox that you want to remove. You can use any value that uniquely identifies the mailbox.
For example: `Name`, `Display name`, `Alias`, `Distinguished name (DN)`, `Canonical DN`, `<domain name>\<account name>`, `Email address`, `GUID`, `LegacyExchangeDN`, `SamAccountName`, `User ID or user principal name (UPN)`.
What identity value are you using in the CSV field `mailbox`?

Answer (score 0):

What I am assuming is happening is that your CSV column of `mailbox` does not match the `identity` of the mailbox

You can use conditions to make sure that you are running `Remove-mailbox` on an actual mailbox:

```
#assuming that "array.csv" has a column named mailbox
Import-Csv "C:\temp\array.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    if((Get-Mailbox -Identity $_.Alias | Measure).Count -eq 1)
    {
        Write-Host "Removing "$_.mailbox -ForegroundColor Green
        Remove-Mailbox -Identity $_.mailbox -Confirm:$false #Here you should add -Whatif before running
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $_.mailbox " not found or not unique" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

}
```

Or, if you are confident that your query is correct, you can ignore the error by sticking with your original script and putting and `-ErrorAction` on `Remove-Mailbox`

Ex:

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\array.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-Mailbox -identity $_.mailbox -confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

To test if csv column `mailbox` matches the `identity` of the mailbox you can run a simple `Get-Mailbox`:

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\array.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Mailbox -identity $_.mailbox 
}
```